# value is undefined when passed in component in angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, api, angular6

I have a Service that calls an API (Http get request) then I call the service within my component to get the data and then assign it to a value. after that I pass the value in the html to another component but it showing as undefined

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../src/app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  passData: any
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.test().subscribe(data => {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i].date = new Date(
            data[i].date.substring(0, 4)+'-'+
            data[i].date.substring(4, 6)+'-'+
            data[i].date.substring(6, 10)+ ' '+data[i].minute)
          }
          this.passData = data;
    });
  }

}
```

below is where I pass in my value to the new component, but showing undefined

```
<div class="card-deck">
   <app-stock-bar  [customTitle]=passData></app-stock-bar>
```

The value of passData when passed is undefined, but if I log it, it will display the value in the console

Comment: Try this - <app-stock-bar  customTitle="passData"></app-stock-bar>

Comment: NO this is not the proper way to do it

Comment: array of objects

Comment: Show the code for authService.test() and clarify what is customTitle?

Comment: We need to see the new component app-stock-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was very simple after some research I found that you can simply use *ngIF to check if the value is present before you load

```
    <app-stock-bar  *ngIf="passData"  [customTitle]="passData"></app-stock-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing the value from parent to child component. You can access it inside onChanges LifeCycle hook.

**Component**

```
@Component({})
export class AppStockBar implements OnChanges{

  @Input() customTitle;
  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log(this.customTitle);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the property binding missing double quotes

```
 <app-stock-bar  [customTitle]="passData"></app-stock-bar>
```

Comment: I mean it's not right anyway. That's not how you pass value in the html.